# I do not understand what (Expressions in statements must only be executed by their side effects) means in my code

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict
var lifetime = 5.0; //lifetime of projectile
var explosion : GameObject; //explosion prefab
var counter : int = 0; //keeps track of player score
var scoreToWin : int = 20; //determines score for player to win
var col : Collider; 

void; OnTriggerEnter(Collider, col);
     {
     //triggers collision on enemy tag
     if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
     {
       Score();     
       Debug.Log("Score!");
       Destroy(col.gameObject);
    //destroys enemy object
        var explo = Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 //destroy the projectile that just caused the trigger collision
    Destroy(explo, 3); // delete the explosion after 3 seconds
 Destroy(gameObject,lifetime);
     }
}

function update()
{
guiText.text = "Score: "+counter;

}

function Score()
{
counter++;
    if (counter == scoreToWin);
            "setTimeout(10000, 5000)";
            Debug.Log (" You Win");
            Application.Quit;
}
```

[Picture of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6InI.png)

After doing some research I have found that the error means that the line of code isn't doing anything. I do not understand however how that could be. As long as my logic of the collision, timeout, and app.quit is correct. I am also trying to find a way to implement my guiText to the screen for player viewing

Comment: Is this TypeScript? Please add proper tags.

Comment: Nope. js. It is in the tag.

Comment: @DarkestDreams It's not actually javascript - it's a language more commonly called UnityScript. Be careful about that one too :)

Comment: Ah.. Makes sense. No clue why unitycalls it a js file then. Even says its js when you go to create it.

Comment: Yeah, its not even close to javascript (only surface syntax is close). It doesn't even follow ecma standard. I suppose they call it that to entice web developers.

Comment: @DarketDreams - yep, historical reasons of web developer attraction. The webplayer was originally what helped Unity gain such widespread adoption so using a language they called "javascript" helped. However, it's been getting increasingly awkward over the years - you can now also code in _real_ javascript ever since they added WebGL support. Use the extension _.jslib_ for that (available when targeting WebGL only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues, but the main one is that you're using semi-colons in the wrong place. Here they are:

```
void; OnTriggerEnter(Collider, col); // Two incorrect semi-colons. Incorrect comma.

// Further down:

if (counter == scoreToWin); // Incorrect semi-colon
        "setTimeout(10000, 5000)"; // What's this expected to do?
        Debug.Log (" You Win"); // OK
        Application.Quit; // Quit is a method
```

## The fixes

You probably meant:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider)
{
 // ...

if(counter == scoreToWin)
{
    Debug.Log("You Win");
    Application.Quit();
}
```

## How am I supposed to use ;?

`;` means *end of a statement* and isn't used when that statement has a *block* (curly brackets). `void Hello(){}` is **one statement**, but it has curly brackets, so no semi-colon is required. `var score=5;` is a statement which doesn't have curly brackets, so a semi-colon is used at the end.

## Scoping

It looks like you're used to using something like Python where indenting also represents scoping. C# and UnityScript ("javascript") aren't like those languages.

```
if(score == max)
{
   // Don't forget those curly brackets!
   // Everything that happens when the score is 'max' goes in here.
}
```

However, there is an instance where those curly brackets aren't required - this is *implicit curly brackets*:

```
if(score == max)
    doSomething(); // *only* this line runs if score is max. Watch out!
    Debug.Log("No matter what score is, this shows up!");
```

When brackets are implied, only the first line after it runs when the `if` is true.

If you didn't put the semi-colon there, you would probably be very confused about why the debug.log shows up all the time, so I would recommend *always* using curly brackets - at least until you're confident with the language.

Comment: setTimeout is expected to delay the application from unexpectedly closing on the player for 5 seconds (5000ms) removing the semicolons and comma's seems to only bring up (expected ;/, in unity debug) the method fix did end the syntax on app.quit though

Comment: @DarkestDreams Ah I was thinking about C# (Most people use C# in Unity these days) - you'd need to use `OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider)` in that case (see the updated answer).

Comment: Trying to learn both languages at the same time begins to leak in to each other. The red flags are gone now. Thanks for your assistance. Would you happen to know of anyway to delay the app.quit? so that it doesnt close as soon as the player wins

Comment: @DarkestDreams In Unity there's a few routes for delaying something but [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is the general route. You wouldn't use it right there though - You'd put it in some other method and start it up with `StartCoroutine`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have too many semi-colons (statement terminators).

Try changing this:

```
if (counter == scoreToWin);
        "setTimeout(10000, 5000)";
        Debug.Log (" You Win");
        Application.Quit;
```

To this:

```
if (counter == scoreToWin)
{
        setTimeout(10000, 5000);
        Debug.Log (" You Win");
        Application.Quit;
}
```

Similar issue in this function definition:

```
void; OnTriggerEnter(Collider, col);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that :

- `void;` does nothing, it is a reserved word not meant to be used alone.
- `"string literal"` does nothing, you have to assing it to a variable or at least do something with it
- `functionname` does nothing you have to invoke it with `()` at the end.

And that's what your JS hinter is complainting about.